# I can only select my Datatable's rows every other time I reload data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My use case is a datatable in which a user may select a row.

My table:

```
ts_table = $('#ts_table').DataTable({
iDisplayLength: 5,
lengthMenu: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
order: [[ 1, "asc" ]],
columns : [
    {data:'ts_id'},
    {data:'ts_name', width: '20%'},
    {data:'ts_desc', width: '80%'}
    ],
columnDefs: [{
    targets: [ 0 ],
    visible: false,
    searchable: false}
    ]
});
```

My event handler code is called by client generated events (document ready and when a data tables source is updated by the user):

```
function process_all_test_sets(msg) {
    if (ts_table.data().any()) {
        ts_table.rows().remove().draw();
    } else {
        all_test_sets_array = msg.data.split("|");
        test_set_list = JSON.parse(all_test_sets_array[1]);
        console.info("Adding rows to test set table.");
        ts_table.rows.add(test_set_list).draw();
        $('#ts_table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
            data = ts_table.row(this).data();
            console.info("Clicked " + this);
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                test_set_test_sets = [];
            }
            else {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                if (test_set_test_sets.length > 0) {
                    test_set_test_sets.shift();
                }
                test_set_test_sets.push(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is that the event handler doesn't add the selected class to my row every other time I try to refresh data (but not the document), even though I can see it populating and clearing test_set_test_sets as it should.

Help?

Thanks.

Comment: if it has class selected you remove the class selected, ok. but in the else, it has no class selected and you try remove it? you dont need to do this?

Comment: try `$('#ts_table tbody tr').on('click', function ()...`, i don't know if it does the same, but then you have a single click listener on each tr and not on the complete tbody. and remove event from the function params, you never touch it so it only takes memory

Comment: @mtizziani The way he did it is actualy better, since the dynamically added `tr` elements within the `tbody` get the event binded to them too. Test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j7209yoj/). Your way of doing it doesn't add the event to new elements.

Comment: @JeffNoel thanks for that info, i did not know it

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that you call `process_all_test_sets()` multiple times and therefore define event handler multiple times.

Instead you need to define your event handler only once and move it out of `process_all_test_sets()`.

For example:

```js
ts_table = $('#ts_table').DataTable({
   // ...
});

$('#ts_table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
   // ...
});

function process_all_test_sets(msg) {
   // ...
});
```

Alternatively you can use [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method to remove previously defined event handler. For example:

```js
$('#ts_table tbody').off('click', 'tr');
$('#ts_table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
   // ...
});
```